# Unable to link Smart Home Action

Tags: google-smart-home

I am trying to link my Smart Home action and it is not working for some specific accounts. I have traced out some logs on our server and found that our API is taking longer for some of the accounts which have more number of devices connected than usual.
So when I try to link the Smart Home Action on the Google Home App, it loads for like 10 seconds and then lands back to the previous screen without getting linked.
My question is, **Is there a default timeout for the requests that Google Home is sending at my end, which I am exceeding?**

Comment: Have you checked your [project logs](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/monitoring-logging#logging) to verify you are seeing timeout errors?

Comment: I get `BACKEND_FAILURE`, although in the logs at my end, my API is returning success response. The error log shows error as follows - severity: "ERROR"
textPayload: "SYNC: Request ID 15658284815629318445 failed with code: BACKEND_FAILURE"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can visit the following link https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/troubleshooting#platform_error_codes and if scroll down to the description for RESPONSE_TIMEOUT error code then it is mentioned that the timeout period for sending a response is 9 seconds for most requests.

If this is not the exact error you are facing then it might be because testing hasn't been enabled on the project. To fix in case this is the issue, AoG Console > Develop > Account Linking > Test (Upper Right Corner).

Comment: Thank you! For some cases my API is taking longer than 9 seconds and that's when the smart home action linking fails.